# Webpack: How to bundle js files + JQuery ?

Tags: jquery, webpack

I'm new to webpack and I'm trying to pack two javascript files that I wrote and the source code of jquery.

To do so, I wrote webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '\\js\\root.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '\\bin',
        filename: 'app.bundle.min.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            include: /\.js$/,
            minimize: true
        })
    ]
};
```

and root.js:

```
require('./jquery-3.2.1.js');
require('./first.js');
require('./second.js');
```

When I run my application I get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

$ is used in one of my js files.

I know that jquery can be loaded as a plugin in webpack, but I want to load it just as any ordinary js file.

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $ = require('./jquery-3.2.1.js');
```

Instead of

```
require('./jquery-3.2.1.js');
```